# Analytics Stops upon Code Deployment

Tags: mongodb, sitecore-client, experience-analytics

I am not sure if anyone ran into this issue before:

We have an in house built tool to deploy code from the build server to specified destinations. Mongo `reports/Custom Analytics` is not working whenever we deploy code to the server and every time this happens `IISReset` fixes the issue.

**Notes:** When we deploy the code we *do not* deploy `Sitecore/App_Config` or any Sitecore specific files but we do deploy `application/project` related files(layouts, sub layouts, .dlls) and also `web config`, `global.asax`.

Is there any way to fix this issue other than resetting IIS?

[image: Analytics Console Log]

Comment: Anything relevant in the log files? Do you know if Mongo is still logging data during this period and its just the reports that are broken?

Comment: other than log files errors/warnings, does this web.config file you are deploying have any analytics entries defined on it that could be overriding the analytics.enabled for example?

Comment: Most of the mongo related activities are performed through agents that have to subscribe to the Heartbeat event. Based on what you're saying, it sounds like enough of the app-pool is being changed (DLL's) to cause the app pool to send a SIGHUP to the application without fully restarting the app pool. When this happens, the Heartbeat is turned off, resulting in hooks and scheduled agents to stop running. Restarting/recycling the app pool in IIS fixes the issue. Check your logs after a deployment to see if you get the "Hosting environment shutdown" message, but no actual recycle.

Comment: If the above helps, I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: @Diego - Nope the config files that I deploy are related to project. No Sitecore Analytics Entries.

Comment: @PeteNavarra - Yes I see below messages when code deployed :    WARN  Sitecore shutting down
WARN  Shutdown message: Change in GLOBAL.ASAX
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown

Comment: According to @peteNavarra it seems that recycle or reset is the only option left to fix this issue. Thanks all and yes we can turn it to an answer.

Comment: @Vamshi what do you mean when you say Mongo reports aren't working? What do you see on the screen, exactly?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko : I added a screenshot of console logs. When this issue happens I see a blank screen in the custom analytics portion when this happens.

Comment: @Vamshi after you see the errors on the screenshot, take a look in Sitecore logs. They'll have more detailed errors. Please include them in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to deployment practices, most of the time when deploying code, the worker process is going to recycle itself in order to pick up the changes that it detected. In some cases, this recycle can cause problems. With that in mind, it is generally a best practice manually recycle the app pool as part of the deployment process.

Most of the MongoDB related activities are performed through agents that have to subscribe to the Heartbeat event. Based on what you're saying, it sounds like enough of the app-pool is being changed (DLL's) to cause the app pool to send a SIGHUP to the application without fully restarting the app pool.

When this happens, the Heartbeat is turned off, resulting in hooks and scheduled agents to stop running.

Restarting/recycling the app pool in IIS fixes the issue. Check your logs after a deployment to see if you get the "Hosting environment shutdown" message, but no actual recycle.